# Size of the NAMENODE and DATANODE in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

What is the size of the NAMENODE and DATANODE and wheather the block and datanode is different or not in hadoop

if input file is 200mb size then how many datanode will be created and how many blocks will created.

Comment: You are missing the hadoop basics here. Please read the "hadoop the definitive guide" and "hadoop operations" books to get clear idea of what hadoop is and get acquainted with the terminology

Comment: I think your question title was not appropriate at all.

Answer (score 0):

NameNode, SecondaryNameNode, JobTracker, DataNode are components in a hadoop cluster.
Blocks are how data is stored on the HDFS.

Datanode can be simply seen as a hard disk(lot of memory - TBs) with a ram and a processor on the network.

Just like you can store many files on a hard disk, you can do that hear as well.

Now if you want to store a 200mb file on a Hadoop-

> v1.0 system or lower, it will be split into 4 blocks of 64mb size
>
> v2.0 System or higher, it will be split into 2 blocks of 128mb size

After this small explanation, I'd revert you to @charles_Babbage's suggestion to go and start with a book or tutorials on youtube.